# How to pass object to postgres

Tags: java, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am using postgres as my database and I want to send Object to Postgres. I am using

> simpleJdbcCall.withCatalogName(datasourceCatalogName).execute(in);

variable **in** is a `map<String, Object>` but i do not know how to use the fields of this object in Postgres.
I went through some links but they all specify passing array to Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question but you can pass to postgres serialized objects from java.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html